# ¿como retroceder a una linea especifica del codigo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas, estoy elaborando el siguiente menu, en el cual cuando se elige la opcion 1 y el identificador de paciente que se introduce es >3500 se imprima ese error por pantalla y se vuelva a pedir que se introduzca un nuevo identificador

he intentado hacerlo con label y goto pero creo que python no lo tiene implementado y no se como podria hacer algo parecido para que se vuelva a pedir que se introduzca un nuevo identificador hasta que sea correcto

```
while True:
        print('1)Datos del paciente')
        print('2)Resumen de variable')
        print('3)Volver')

        opc=input('Elija una opción: ')
        if opc=='1':

            identificador_paciente=int(input('Introduzca un identificador de paciente: '))
            if 1<=identificador_paciente<=3500:
                print ('hola')

            else:
                print('Lo siento, el identificador de paciente introducido no es válido')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El uso `goto` en la inmensa mayoría de los casos está considerada una mala práctica en los lenguajes que lo soportan como C. Es una instrucción propia de los primeros lenguajes de programación que a partir de la aparición de la programación estructurada pasó a considerarse "malvada" en general. La causa principal es que a la mínima que el programa sea algo extenso hace que sea muy difícil seguir el flujo de éste y siendo fácil terminar con códigos  inconsistentes, complicados de mantener y muy poco legibles.

Python como lenguaje de alto nivel y que aboga por la legibilidad del código como fundamento no implementa la instrucción `goto` como es lógico. Combinando `for`/`while`, condicionales, `try`/`except` y funciones se puede conseguir como mínimo lo mismo con un código mucho más legible y fácil de mantener. Puedes usar otro ciclo `while`:

```
while True:
    print('1)Datos del paciente')
    print('2)Resumen de variable')
    print('3)Volver')

    opc = input('Elija una opción: ')
    if opc == '1':
        identificador_paciente = int(input('Introduzca un identificador de paciente: '))
        while not 1 <= identificador_paciente <= 3500:
            print('Lo siento, el identificador de paciente introducido no es válido')
            identificador_paciente = int(input("Introduzca un identificador de paciente válido: "))
        print("Hola")
```

O usando `break`:

```
while True:
    print('1)Datos del paciente')
    print('2)Resumen de variable')
    print('3)Volver')

    opc = input('Elija una opción: ')
    if opc == '1':
        while True:
            identificador_paciente = int(input('Introduzca un identificador de paciente: '))
            if 1 <= identificador_paciente <= 3500:
                print('hola')
                break
            else:
                print('Lo siento, el identificador de paciente introducido no es válido')
```